# How to test observer?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin, rx-java

I would test presenter like this:

```
class MostPopularPresenter @Inject constructor(val mostPopularUseCase: MostPopularUseCase) 
: Presenter<MostPopularView>() {

    fun requestMostPopular(page: Int, update: Boolean) {
        if (page <= 6)
            mostPopularUseCase.execute(MostPopularObserver(), MostPopularUseCase.Params.createQuery(page, 15, update))
    }

    inner class MostPopularObserver : DisposableSingleObserver<MostPopularModel>() {

        override fun onSuccess(t: MostPopularModel) {
            this@MostPopularPresenter.view?.populateRecyclerList(t)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
            this@MostPopularPresenter.view?.showError()
        }
    }
}
```

I have problem how to mock observer and force it to throw error or return value on success. I'm using mockito/junit. Can someone point me how to achieve it? Maybe my code is untestable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `observer` is an object that shouldn't be really tested. It has been already tested when it has been developed by a third developer, although there are some people that say, with a part of reason, that you should also test a third party library in order to ensure that it doesn't break your code between versions.

So, if you don't test the `observer`... how do you test your code? Simply, what you really need to test is the **presenter** itself. The code running inside the `observer` is part of the presenter. So instead of mocking the `observer` **mock the `useCase`**:

```
test useCaseFails() {
    val usecase = // mock use case
    when(usecase.execute(...))
        .thenAnswer(/* receive the observer as first parameter
                       and make it emit an error */)
    val presenter = ...
    presenter.requestMostPopular(...)
    // assert that presenter.view?.showError has been called
}
```

Another way of doing this (at least this is the way I usually code) is to make the `useCase` return an `observable` and subscribe it in the `presenter`:

```
class MostPopularPresenter @Inject constructor(val mostPopularUseCase: MostPopularUseCase) 
    : Presenter<MostPopularView>() {

    private var lateinit observer : Disposable

    fun requestMostPopular(page: Int, update: Boolean) {
        if (page <= 6)
            disposable = mostPopularUseCase.execute(MostPopularUseCase.Params.createQuery(page, 15, update))
                .subscribe(t -> view?.populateRecyclerList(t),
                           e -> view?.showError())
    }
}
```

This way you can easily mock your `useCase` so it returns a `Subject` you can control:

```
test useCaseFails() {
    val usecase = // mock use case
    val subject = PublishSubject()
    when(usecase.execute(...))
        .thenReturn(subject)
    val presenter = ...
    presenter.requestMostPopular(...)
    subject.emitError(...) // <- pseudocode
    // assert that presenter.view?.showError has been called
}
```

Comment: I really like "thenAnswer" mechanism. I wrote test like you said and I it works very well. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is the intended way to use `thenAnswer` or it's just a little hack. If that helps you I'll update my answer with another way of doing that

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are not many cases where it is absolutely not possible to test. As far as I see it, you have a few options:

- Put the observer into the constructor with a default value (but this might have some downsides with your dependency injection)
- Put the observer into the function with a default value. This would work, but you have to choose if your API should contain this
- Use the observer as property. In the test you can override this one.

All this variants would work and are listed here:

```
// observer in constructor
class MostPopularPresenter @Inject constructor(val mostPopularUseCase: MostPopularUseCase, val observer: DisposableSingleObserver<MostPopularModel> = MostPopularObserver())
    : Presenter<MostPopularView>() {

    // observer as property
    internal var observer: DisposableSingleObserver<MostPopularModel> = MostPopularObserver() 

    // observer in function
    fun requestMostPopular(page: Int, update: Boolean, observer: DisposableSingleObserver<MostPopularModel> = MostPopularObserver()) {
        if (page <= 6)
            mostPopularUseCase.execute(observer, MostPopularUseCase.Params.createQuery(page, 15, update))
    }
}

internal class MostPopularObserver : DisposableSingleObserver<MostPopularModel>() { ... }
```

It would be even nicer, if you us a `DisposableSingleObserverFactory` and create the observer when it's needed.

```
class MostPopularPresenter @Inject constructor(val mostPopularUseCase: MostPopularUseCase, val observerFactory: DisposableSingleObserverFactory<MostPopularModel> = MostPopularObserverFactorty())
    : Presenter<MostPopularView>() {

    internal var observerFactory: DisposableSingleObserverFactory<MostPopularModel> = MostPopularObserverFactory()

    fun requestMostPopular(page: Int, update: Boolean, observerFactory: DisposableSingleObserverFactory<MostPopularModel> = MostPopularObserver()) {
        if (page <= 6)
            mostPopularUseCase.execute(observerFactory.create(), MostPopularUseCase.Params.createQuery(page, 15, update))
    }
}

internal class MostPopularObserver : DisposableSingleObserver<MostPopularModel>() {
```